# Map3D capabilities AutoDesk engine

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

Does the Forge design automation AutoCad engine also support commands from the Civil3D and Map3D packages (which are a kind of extension of AutoCad)? Could not find any in the documentation, primarily looking for this because attached Object Data in Map3d does not seem to be extracted to the metadata when converting in the model derivative Api.

Comment: Design Automation engine of AutoCAD can identify Civil3D and Map3D objects (Object Enabler is available), but the engine does not expose specific commands of these products. Could you provide a demo drawing and elaborate what kind of data your want to extract? I can double check if it is supported or any tricks to get them

Comment: Specifically looking to get [Object Data](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-map-3d/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/MAP3D-Use/files/GUID-300DBB1E-D5BD-44E7-A50E-D11EB3B3EE49-htm.html). The file I'm currently testing with is not sharable but will look into getting you one.

Comment: ok, I got it. thanks. It looks they are additional properties attaching to an entity. I would think if it is possible to see them by pure AutoCAD environment. if yes, the Design Automation should be able to get them as well. I will try to find a demo drawing and verify this. It would take some time to get back to you.

Comment: I was on a short holiday and just an update with my progress: I tried to check if plain AutoCAD API can extract data of OD Table, but it looks impossible. So I am asking engineer team of Design Automation. will keep you update

Comment: just some updates: I got to know typically, the custom properties might be defined in Object Enabler (in the context of plain AutoCAD, Map3D is also a kind of custom object), OR defined by Property Extension (by ActiveX) which should be running on specific AutoCAD vertical product. If the former, it can be dumped by List command. By my test with Design Automation or local AutoCAD, the OD Table of Map3D is not available with List command.. I am further checking with team if any other way could be available, or we have to wait for DA supports vertical products

Comment: This is already very helpful, thank you! I hope somehow we can get that OD Table data, or figure out a timeline for Forge support. This is part of a broader investigation I'm doing on what metadata/properties are supported by model derivative and/or in is extractable in combination with design automation. In the API documentation I could not find such an overview and we need that info to determine the feasability of a Forge solution.